# CSS/HTML Page Width

Tags: html, css

(No answers have worked as of yet, please keep answering)

http://gyazo.com/952d354b05e4a4a4cef08e74f8b0253d

http://gyazo.com/e8cc5ae0bcd0464eb074c4674d2896fb

As you can see from these images, I have created the navbar for my website but my website is too wide, it means that you have to scroll to reach the end of it, how would I change the width so it only goes up to the end of the navbar?

That is all my CSS for the navbar that I have used:

```
   #title {
   position:relative;
   margin:17px 1680px 30px 15px;
       }
       #banner {
   border:1px solid #4A4A4A;
   width:1903;
   height:110;
   background-color:#4A4A4A;
   margin-left:0px;
   position:absolute;
   top:-10px;
   border-radius:15px;
       }
       #navbar {
   position:fixed;
   left:50%;
   margin-top:2px;

       }
       ul {
   list-style-type:none;
   margin:-115px;
       }
       li {    
   display:inline;
   padding:9px;
   border:4px solid;
   font-family:Bebas;
   font-size:25px;
   font-weight:bold;
   color:#FFFFFF;
   border-radius:10px;
   background-color:#000000;
   margin-left:2.5em;
       }
```

This is my HTML code aswell:

```
    <html>

    <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="todd.css"/>
    <title>Home</title>

    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#ABABAB">
 <div>
   <div id="banner">
     <a href="file:///C:/Users/Todd/Desktop/todd.html"><img         src="file:///C:/Users/Todd/Desktop/Todd.png" id="title"></a>
       <div id="navbar">         
         <ul>
           <a href="file:///C:/Users/Todd/Desktop/todd.html"><li>Home</li></a>                     
           <li>Not Finished</li>                       
           <li>Not Finished</li>                       
           <li>Not Finished</li>          
         <ul>   
       </div>            
     </img>
   </div>
      </div>
      </body>



     </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If you put the relevant code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), it will be easier for people to see the problem and fix it.

Comment: try this  `width:1903;
   height:110;` to  `width:100%;   height:110px;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Width of my website needs changing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889458/width-of-my-website-needs-changing)

Comment: *`(No answers have worked as of yet, please keep answering)`* - this **is not** how [so] works.

Comment: *No answers have worked as of yet, please keep answering* - it would greatly help if you could provide some more details as to what you really want, want you are currently getting, etc.   If the answers provided haven't fixed the issue, then you are not describing the problem enough for us to be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things I see here...

Your navbar has this line:

```
   width:1903;
```

If you don't want the navbar to be so wide, you should shrink this way down.

Additionally, if you want to keep the site from expanding so wide, you can also set the width for the `html` and `body` tags, like so:

```
html, body {width: 1024px}
```

Hopefully that helps...

**EDIT**

At second glance, I see your margin is also set very wide here:

```
   margin:17px 1680px 30px 15px;
```

Shrinking the 1680 down will keep the bar from expanding so wide.   This appears to be the main cause of your title bar extending out so wide.

Answer (score 0):

If you use min-width the size of the page should minimise in order to fit all the content in.

```
#banner { 
     min-width: 1903px;
}
```